# Button size not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I have two sites using the same theme. One looks fine and is at http://yourwhiteknight.com/. The other one has one small problem, there is a button under the phone number at the top that says Manufactured Homes. You can see it here: http://realestate.yourwhiteknight.com/

The button on the later site is smaller than the the first site and it shouldn't be. The code is practically the same but I can't find where it is making the button smaller.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/manufactured/">
     <img class="homes" width="233" height="38" src="http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/m.homes-tab.png">
</a>
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you even inspect, bro?

Comment: On the site where it's working, your class is set to 'homes new', whereas in the one where it's smaller, it's set to 'homes' - that might be the problem?

Comment: Didn't make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the bootstrap CSS is affecting the img `max-width` with this code:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto\9;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

So you can override it with:

```
img.homes {max-width:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your First site you have css like this,

```
   max-width: 233px !important;
   height: 38px;
```

so and your other website just put this css code,

```
    max-width: 223px;
    width: 223px;
    height: 38px;
```